# How to fix error messages to make a line plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, predict

I'm trying to make a line plot of the relationship of density on the real scale with the covariate in the top half-normal model (hn.l.s), based on estimates from that model. How do I get rid of the 2 error messages and make a line plot?

```
dist <- seq(0, 60, 15)
obs <- as.matrix(dat[, 1:4])
site_covs <- data.frame(shrub = dat[, c("d.shrub")], light=dat[, c("light")])
umf<-unmarkedFrameDS(y = obs, siteCovs = site_covs, dist.breaks = c(dist), 
                     survey = "point", unitsIn = "m")
hn.l.s <- distsamp(~light~shrub, umf, keyfun = "halfnorm", output = "density", 
                   unitsOut = "ha")
pred.hn.l.s <- predict(hn.l.s, "state", se.fit = TRUE)
backTransform(hn.l.s, type = "state")
```

> Error in .local(obj, ...) :
>
> Cannot directly backTransform an unmarkedEstimate with length > 1.

```
plot(hn.l.s, pred.hn.l.s, type = "l", ylim = c(0,60), xlab = "Distance", 
     ylab = "Detection probability")
```

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
>
> 'x' and 'y' lengths differ